# toggle after show() not working in the second time

Tags: jquery

I have a span that I want to hide and show another on click. When I show this second span it will show an effect.

The problem is, it only works on the first click. Not in the second. (third works fine, but not on the fourth and so on).

**after `unclick` and click on it again it will not show the animation.**

what is wrong? why can't see the animation after unclick and click again?

js

```
$(function() {
 $( document ).on( "click", "#click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#unclick').show();

  $('#unclick').toggleClass("l_toggle"); //work only first time?

 });


 $( document ).on( "click", "#unclick", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#click').show();
 });





});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b7c34kgv/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `l_toggle` class when you hide the `unclick`:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#unclick", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  // add this
  $('#unclick').removeClass("l_toggle");
  $('#click').show();
 });
```

Comment: @RickJoe great that it works ;) Consider marking the answer as accepted, so others will know that the solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$('#unclick').toggleClass("l_toggle");` to the click handler for `#unclick`

```
$(function() {
 $( document ).on( "click", "#click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#unclick').show();

   $('#unclick').toggleClass("l_toggle");

 });


 $( document ).on( "click", "#unclick", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#click').show();
  $('#unclick').toggleClass("l_toggle"); // add this
 });





});
```

```js
$(function() {
 $( document ).on( "click", "#click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#unclick').show();
  
   $('#unclick').toggleClass("l_toggle");
  
 });


 $( document ).on( "click", "#unclick", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('#click').show();
  $('#unclick').toggleClass("l_toggle"); // add this
 });





});
```

```css
#unclick img{
  width:30px;
}

#unclick{
  display:none;
}

.l_toggle img{
  animation-name: spin; 
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes spin { 
 25% { transform: scale(1.2); }
 33% { transform:rotate(35deg); } 
 66% { transform:rotate(-35deg); }
 100% { transform:rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id=click>click</span>

<span id=unclick><img src=http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png>unclick</span>
```